# Perl - cast hash to array without using further variable

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, casting

is possible to cast hash to array in perl but without using further variable ?
This works as expected but another variable (@arr) is used:

```
perl -wlae '%hash=(name=>"linus", forename=>"torvalds "); @arr=%hash; print "@arr"'
```

I have tried those but neither worked (BTW what do they do ?):

```
perl -wlae '%hash=(name=>"linus", forename=>"torvalds "); print "@hash"'
perl -wlae '%hash=(name=>"linus", forename=>"torvalds "); print "%@hash"'
perl -wlae '%hash=(name=>"linus", forename=>"torvalds "); print "@%hash"'
```

Comment: Not sure what you expect those to do, since you're using completely different variable names.

Comment: I just wonder if is possible to cast hash to array without need to declare array variable.

Comment: I know, but why did you expect the things you tried to do anything? You assign a variable named `hash`, then use `arr` in your print statements even though you didn't assign it.

Comment: Oh, sorry now it is fixed, it was just a typo

Comment: My assumption is that hashes and arrays are very similar (array indexed by number, hashes by key) structures so I assume that I can use same techniques to accessing, processing it etc. I am interested in how they are represented in memory, how perl "sees" them etc.

Comment: By any reasonable definition of the term, "Torvalds" is not Linus Torvalds' "forename".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
perl -wlae '%hash=(name=>"linus", forename=>"torvalds "); print (%hash);'
```

Putting an expression in parentheses evaluates it in a list context, just like assigning to a list variable does.

In the case of `print`, this casting is unnecessary, since it uses list context for both arrays and hashes. But if you want to do other array-style things with a hash, you can use this, e.g.

```
$first = (%hash)[0];
echo $first;
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain what does parentheses do ?

Comment: Added explanation in answer.

Comment: -1 : Your explanation makes no sense. `print %hash;` works just fine.

Comment: @Zaid See the additional detail I just added.

Comment: Parentheses don't force evaluation in list context. All they do is impose a specific order of evaluation. As long as a subroutine has no prototype, the parameters of any call are evaluated in list context, with or without any parentheses.